# Let $f$ be injective and discontinuous at some point $c$. Can its inverse be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

$f$ is injective at an interval $[a,b]$, but discontinuous at some point $c$ in the same interval. I need to prove that its inverse is continuous at that interval.

Should I consider what is the inverse of an inverse essentially?

[image]

Comment: Intuitively the answer is no, because think about it you can see where a function is discontinuous by looking at the graph, it will have a break at $(c,f(c))$.  You can't draw it without lifting your pencil.  Since $f$ is bijective you can stand on the $y$-axis instead of the $x$-axis and it still looks like a function.  And you'd still see a break at $(c,f(c))$ in the graph. You still can't draw it without lifting your pencil.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: the OP wanted help with a proof.

Comment: @RobArthan That's why I didn't post as an answer... obviously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $g = f^{-1} : [\alpha, \beta] \to [a, b]$ is continuous. Then it is a continuous bijection between $[\alpha, \beta]$ and $[a, b]$. By the intermediate value theorem, this means $g$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. Let's assume it strictly increasing. Then $f = g^{-1}$ must be a strictly increasing bijection between $[a, b]$ and $[\alpha, \beta]$. I now leave it to you to show that a strictly increasing bijection between two intervals is continuous. (Hint: show that the inverse image of an open interval is an open interval.) The case when $g$ is strictly decreasing is similar.

The conclusion is that if $f : [a, b] \to \Bbb{R}$ is discontinuous, then so is $f^{-1}$ (provided the image of $f$ is an interval).